# Mustermann::CompileError in URL

Tags: ruby, string, url, sinatra

I've got a Sinatra-powered blog with the following method:

```
module Tir
  module Blog
    class Article

      def url
        [Tir::Config.domain, meta('relative_path')].join
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Calling this on an Article instance outputs the full URI of the article, like:

```
"http://example.com/2018/07/08/test-article"
```

The amazing Mustermann gives me the following error:

> Mustermann::CompileError: capture name can't be empty: "/http://example.com/2018/07/08/test-article"

1. Why does it insert a forward slash at the beginning of the string?
2. Why is it so restrictive wrt generated strings that aren't even Sinatra routes?
3. How do I get rid of this problem?

Thanks.

**EDIT 29.08.2018:**
Turns out, Sinatra / Mustermann were blocking these strings because they **were** routes. My main method for generating dynamic article routes was this:

```
articles = []

Dir.glob('articles/*.mdown') do |file|
 article = initialize_article file
 if article.ready?
   get("/#{article.url}") do
    erb :'articles/article',
    :locals => { :article => article },
    :layout => :'articles/layout_article'
   end
   articles << article
 end
end
```

The improved version uses a different method in the `get` block:

```
#articles.rb

articles = []

Dir.glob('articles/*.mdown') do |file|
 article = initialize_article file
 if article.ready?
   get("/#{article.relative_path}") do
    erb :'articles/article',
    :locals => { :article => article },
    :layout => :'articles/layout_article'
   end
   articles << article
 end
end
```

Method definitions:

```
#blog.rb

def relative_path
 meta('relative_path')
end

def url
 [Tir::Config.domain, meta('relative_path')].join
end
```

So now the `url` method isn't ever called in a route, only on an article object in one of the views — hence no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sinatra route helpers and Mustermann itself do not accept full URLs as patterns, only paths - you can't put hostnames in them. Mustermann's [README](https://github.com/sinatra/mustermann) provide full list of supported pattern types and all samples there show paths. As you called it, 'restrictive' behaviour is normal because it's not a general purpose pattern matching library - it's dedicated specifically to handling URL paths.

If you wan't to specify hostname for Sinatra route, you can do it with optional `host_name` parameter.

```
get '/2018/07/08/test-article', host_name: 'example.com' do
  erb :article  
end
```

If you want to use Mustermann for custom matching, the `uri-template` pattern type listed in the docs works with full URLs. You will have to install `mustermann-contrib` gem and get a grasp of slightly different pattern syntax.

```
irb(main):011:0> require 'mustermann'
=> true
irb(main):012:0> pattern = Mustermann.new("http://example.com/2018/07/08/{slug}", type: 'uri-template')
=> #<Mustermann::Template:"http://example.com/2018/07/08/{slug}">
irb(main):013:0> pattern.match "http://example.com/2018/07/08/test-article"
=> #<MatchData "http://example.com/2018/07/08/test-article" slug:"test-article">
```

Comment: Thanks — I hadn't formulated my question correctly, corrections above.

Comment: @abbottjam you're welcome, now it's clear what the problem was. I hope the answer brought something of value anyway.

Comment: Absolutely — it was your answer that prompted me to look in the right direction and it also contains a lot of valuable info I didn't know.